# Shell script- CURL script returning error

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, curl

This is getting a bit tricky. I have a shell script to create tasks in our JIRA. I'am running it on Ubuntu Server (a newbie).

I have a variable in the script as follows:

```
SCRIPT="curl -D- -u $USER:$PASSWORD -X POST --data @$SAMPLE_FILE -H \"Content-Type:   application/json\" $REST_URL"
```

I echo this script and run it in using $SCRIPT my shell script. When i bash my script, it always returns an error `"curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'application'"`.

But if i try to run the printed SCRIPT(which i echoed) alone, it creates a task. I know it is a small problem but i'm not able to get it!

Any suggestions?

Comment: How do you execute the command in $SCRIPT ? I don't recall it correctly, but I remember there were some caveats about how to execute something like that. You might also want to try `exec "$SCRIPT"` or `exec $SCRIPT` or `$( $SCRIPT )`. I need to test this when I am at home. Please also escape `$SAMPLE_FILE` and `$USER:$PASSWORD` using `\"` since you cannot be sure if they contain whitespaces.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I just ran it as **$SCRIPT**. But i just tried all of your suggestions(exec "$SCRIPT" or exec $SCRIPT or $( $SCRIPT ) ) but in vain. Or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the [bash tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info), we can run your code through [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) to automatically check for common problems:

```
$ shellcheck yourscript

In yourscript line 1:
SCRIPT="curl... -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" $REST_URL"
       ^-- SC2089: Quotes/backslashes will be treated literally. Use an array.

In yourscript line 2:
$SCRIPT
^-- SC2090: Quotes/backslashes in this variable will not be respected.
```

Ok, then [let's use an array](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2089):

```
command=(curl -D- -u "$USER:$PASSWORD" -X POST --data "@$SAMPLE_FILE" -H "Content-Type:   application/json" "$REST_URL")

# Print what we'll execute:
printf "%q " "${command[@]}"
echo

# Execute it:
"${command[@]}"
```